# apt-get remove wants to remove and upgrade at the same time

Tags: apt, postgresql

I updated an installation of postgresql-14 following this document:

https://www.kostolansky.sk/posts/upgrading-to-postgresql-15/

Everything worked fine until I entered `sudo apt-get remove postgresql-14`

The result is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
The following additional packages will be installed:  
  postgresql postgresql-16 postgresql-client-16  
Suggested packages:  
  postgresql-doc postgresql-doc-16  
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  postgresql-14  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  postgresql-16 postgresql-client-16  
The following packages will be upgraded:  
  postgresql
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
Need to get 20.0 MB of archives.  
After this operation, 16.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I cancelled the process because I don't want postgresql-16 to be installed. I (unfortunately) did this on another machine and it broke my replication completely.

I couldn't find an option to suppress the update and hope someone here can help.

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: It's only coincidentally an update. You likely have some package installed that depends upon postgresql. When you uninstall postgresql-14, apt looks around for a way to satisfy the dependency and sees another available that happens to be -16.

Comment: Reading your output was wise. Good job!